# Symfony2 MongoDB Doctrine Inheritance

Tags: mongodb, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, mappedsuperclass

I come with a little problem that I tried to understand in vain...
I have 2 classes. One is an abstract Document called "SpecificIndividual" and the other one is a regular Document called "Individual".

This is what I want to do :
SpecificIndividual has some properties and some getters/setters methods.
Individual inherits SpecificIndividual and has its own properties and getters/setters methods.

I used MappedSuperClass inheritance with COLLECTION_PER_CLASS type.

My problem is that when I use "doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents" command, it generates all getters/setters methods for the abstract class (this is what I want), all getters/setters methods for the child class (this is also what I want) BUT it duplicates all of the abstract class getters/setters methods into the child class (this has no sense at all in inheritance).

I'm probably doing something wrong, since it worked when I was using MySQL and Entities, but since I moved to MongoDB, I can't find the proper way to do this.

Here are my classes :
First, **SpecificIndividual** :

```
namespace SpecificBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * SpecificIndividual
 *
 * @MongoDB\Document
 * @MongoDB\InheritanceType("COLLECTION_PER_CLASS")
 */
abstract class Individual
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $individual_id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Boolean
     */
    protected $chiped;

    /**
     * Get individualId
     *
     * @return id $individualId
     */
    public function getIndividualId()
    {
        return $this->individual_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set chiped
     *
     * @param boolean $chiped
     * @return self
     */
    public function setChiped($chiped)
    {
        $this->chiped = $chiped;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get chiped
     *
     * @return boolean $chiped
     */
    public function getChiped()
    {
        return $this->chiped;
    }
}
```

and the child class Individual :

```
namespace ChildBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

use SpecificBundle\Document\Individual as SpecificIndividual;

/**
 * Individual
 *
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="individuals")
 */
class Individual extends SpecificIndividual
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $someString;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    /**
     * Set someString
     *
     * @param String $someString
     * @return self
     */
    public function setSomeString(String $someString)
    {
        $this->someString = $someString;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get someString
     *
     * @return String $someString
     */
    public function getSomeString()
    {
        return $this->someString;
    }
}
```

I count on you all guys for some help !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add "@MongoDB\MappedSuperclass" to annotation of your abstract class

Link do the documentation http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Your code sample

```
namespace SpecificBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * SpecificIndividual
 * 
 * @MongoDB\MappedSuperclass
 * @MongoDB\Document
 * @MongoDB\InheritanceType("COLLECTION_PER_CLASS")
 */
abstract class Individual
{
```

Comment: That was it, I found it the same week but thanks a lot for your help anyway :)